# PHPでデータベースに画像を挿入するやり方

Tags: php

PHPでデータベースに画像を挿入するやり方がいまいちわかりません。
イメージでは

- イメージ要素に画像のディレクトリを変数で入れる。
- 画像のディレクトリはデータベースで管理する。

らしいのですが、どのように行えばいいかわかりません。

一応このような処理は作成したのですが、上手く動きません。
お手数をおかけしますがご教授お願い致します。

```
if ($_FILES['new_img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

                $chk_picture = getimagesize($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name']);

                if ($chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/png' || $chk_picture['mime'] === 'image/jpeg') {

                    if ($chk_picture[0] <= 500 && ($chk_picture[1] <= 500)) {

                        $mime = $chk_picture['mime'];
                        switch ($mime) {
                            case 'image/png':
                                $type = '.png';
                                break;
                            case 'image/jpeg':
                                $type = '.jpg';
                                break;
                        }

                        $upload = $uploaddir . date('YmdHis') . rand(0, 10000) . $type;
                        
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['new_img']['tmp_name'], $upload);
                    } else {
                        $err_msg[] = 'ファイルは縦と横500px以内にしてください';
                    }
                } else {
                    $err_msg[] = 'PNGかJPEG形式のファイルをアップロードしてください';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ファイルを選択してください';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

言葉の通りだと思います。
画像を挿入するのではなくアップロードしたディレクトリパスを文字列としてデータベースに保存することになります。

例えば、test.jpgを受け取って

```
https://example.com/upload/test.jpg
```

に保存したとします。

そしてデータベースに保存する内容は

```
https://example.com/upload/test.jpg
```

だったり

```
upload/test.jpg
```

だったり

```
test.jpg
```

の文字列をデータベースに保存します。それは要件に合わせてご自身で決めてください。

そして画像をHTML上に表示したいときは

```
<img src="<?php echo $img_url ※img_urlにはDBからとってきたデータが入っている想定?>">
```

のように表示します。

Comment: 実用上は「アップロードされたファイルが本当に jpeg 形式か」「ウイルスを含んでいないか」「アップロードされた時のファイル名をそのまま用いてよいか（重複しないかとか、セキュリティ的に問題ないかとか）」などなどデータベースに登録する前にやらなきゃならない処理がいっぱいあります（けど本題と離れるので省略）。画像そのものを BLOB として直接データベースに保存するのもありなのかもしれないけど案件次第っスね。